Problem with static files returning 404 in Flask and FastAPI applications
I'm running into an issue where I have two applications on a server, one using Flask and the other using FastAPI, both running via Gunicorn. I've connected a domain, and everything seems to work except for static file loading.
For example, when trying to access:
https://test.com/static/js/somejs.js

I get a 404 Not Found error. However, if I add a trailing slash manualy, like this:
https://test.com/static/js/somejs.js/

the file loads correctly.
How can I fix this issue, and ensure the files are accessible without needing to append a trailing slash?
My nginx config:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name translate.site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rembg.site.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    }
}

If i make a config without a subdomain, for example, to the main page, then everything is loaded and works
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    }
}


Ideally, nginx should be serving the static files, not python
